# What is the Japanese human origin myth?

Tags: japanese, shinto

How did Shinto (the traditional Japanese polytheistic religion) explain human origin?

Also, does it have a flood myth?

Answer (score 4):

The Yamata no Orochi (八岐大蛇) is actually ‘the flood myth’ of Japan. The 8 heads of Orochi are actually 8 rivers. Can’t remember the source, will update again if possible.

Answer (score 4):

The [Kojiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kojiki) of Shinto states the origins of mankind as an action of Izanami-no-Mikoto:

> Izanami started his cleansing rites and in doing so he created the
>   Goddess of the seas and the Goddess of the moon by washing his left
>   and right eyes. He then created the God of storms out of his nostril
>   and after all this was done he created the first humans.

I should probably also point out that the term "polytheism" as it is understood in the West doesn't really apply to Shinto. The term "kami" describes a spirit or essence that is very much part of the world. Naturalistic animism would probably be a better description.